# Laravel4.2 IF locale statement

Tags: laravel, localization, locale

I have one question, I'm developing a multi-lang site and struggling of displaying data for each lang. Can I write a IF statement where it detects current locale, for example:

```
@if('locale' = 'lv')
   @foreach($slides_lv as $slide)
        <img src="{{ $slide->path }}">
   @endforeach
@endif
@if('locale' = 'en')
   @foreach($slides_en as $slide)
        <img src="{{ $slide->path }}">
   @endforeach
@endif
@if('locale' = 'ru')
   @foreach($slides_ru as $slide)
        <img src="{{ $slide->path }}">
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Or there is some better way to do it in Laravel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<?php 
    $varName = 'slides_' . App::getLocale();
?>
@foreach ($$varName as $slide)
    <img src="{{ $slide->path }}">
@endforeach
```

`App::getLocale()` will return the locale (in your case 'lv', 'en' etc).

So you build a dynamic variable name based on it and the use it for your foreach loop.

Take care